# create shortcut phrase for an application

Tags: windows-xp, shortcut

I want to setup a shortcut phrase for one of my exe. I mean when i type & run "ABC" inside windows>run dialog box the application should launch.
For your information
I am using windows xp, and the application is a normal windows application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you need to create an executable called "abc.exe" that would launch your application. You also need to make sure "abc.exe" is in the `PATH` (or add the executable in a folder like `windows\system32`)

Comment: into syss32 folder? Do not fancy playing around windows system folder. I would prefer a cleaner way of doing this

Comment: Then simply put "abc.exe" in your application folder and add the path to the Windows' PATH variable.

Comment: It should work, but note that you cannot do it from a DOS session (i.e. `set PATH` won't set the system-wide path). Try to follow the instructions there: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm and just add the folder where your app is located to the PATH variable.

Comment: Previously i had added new env var, now just added my exe folder path in "path" variable. It works fine. Thanks